# Find a file that has a certain word inside that file.

Tags: bash

So basically I have three files, two with permission 744 and one with 601 and I want to list the names of the files that have permission 744 and in addition, it also have to have string "def" anywhere in the lines of the file.

All I got is how to print out if they have permission 744:

```
find * -perm 744
```

How do I get it so it can check for string "def"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow your current options with

```
-exec grep -l def {} +
```

e.g.,

```
find * -perm 744 -exec grep -l def {} +
```

The `-l` option of grep tells it to just list the names of files where a match occurs, and since that is the only action for `find`, the output of `grep` will be all that you see.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

`find * -perm 744 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l def`